# Keypress not working for Edit widget in Urwid

Tags: python, user-input, urwid

I'm trying to make a terminal application in Python using Urwid.

```py
import urwid
class Guess():
    def __init__(self):
        self.guess = urwid.Edit(align='center')

    def keypress(self, size, key):
        if key.lower() == 'enter':
            user_guess = self.guess.edit_text
            self.guess.edit_text = " "
            self.check_guess(user_guess)
```

This is the part where I need input from the user which I then need to send to another function.

The documentation for the `keypress()` method is not at all helpful. I looked at other people's codes, and I tried it using the above, along with a few other ways I found while surfing the internet but got no luck.

Could someone explain to me the exact functioning of the `keypress()` method and how I can achieve what I wan?

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?
Note that the keypress is a method of a widget -- in the piece of code you provided, the Guess class seems to be a regular class.

Answer (score 0):

urwid is [Console user interface library for Python](http://urwid.org/).

if you want to trace kyepress try below,

```
pip install keyboard
```

import keyboard  # using module keyboard

```
def keypress(self, size, key):
    if keyboard.is_pressed('enter'):
        user_guess = self.guess.edit_text
        self.guess.edit_text = " "
        self.check_guess(user_guess)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that actually makes no difference... Nothing happens.

Comment: your have to call your method. self.keypress() something like that

Answer (score 0):

keypress is internal method of Edit class, this

```
class Guess():
    def __init__(self):
        self.guess = urwid.Edit(align='center')
```

has to be changed to this to be able to inherit from Edit

```
class Guess(urwid.Filler)
```

This your own keypress implemenation has to inherit from Edit, change from

```
def keypress(self, size, key):
    if key.lower() == 'enter':
```

to this

```
    # keep same behavior as in keypress in Edit
    return super(Guess, self).keypress(size, key)
```

The whole program will like this

```
import urwid


def exit_on_q(key):
    if key in ('q', 'Q'):
        raise urwid.ExitMainLoop()


# class is inheritance of Filler class Edit
class Guess(urwid.Filler):

    def keypress(self, size, key):
        if key.lower() == 'enter':
            # your own implementation of keypress after enter
            user_guess = guess.edit_text
            self.original_widget = urwid.Text('your guess: {},     Q(q)uit'.format(user_guess))
            return
        # keep same behavior as in keypress in Edit
        return super(Guess, self).keypress(size, key)


# Edit(with internal keypress()
guess = urwid.Edit('guess who?', align='center')
filler = Guess(guess)
loop = urwid.MainLoop(filler, unhandled_input=exit_on_q)
loop.run()
```